# mysql error: Can't create a new thread (errno 11)

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-12.04, percona

I have a db server running Percona Xtradb server, and 5 slaves. I always get the error

> mysql error: Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out
>   of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible
>   OS-dependent bug

Though i set ulimited

```
root@master:~# ulimit -a
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority (-e) 0
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals (-i) 2062915
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files (-n) 1000000
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 1000000
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks (-x) unlimited





root@master:~# cat /proc/`pidof mysqld`/limits | egrep "(processes|files)"Max processes 1000000 1000000 processes
Max open files 1000000 1000000 files
```

I really dont know what's going on? Please help me.

Comment: Probably the mysql thread limit is configurable thru `/etc/mysql.conf` or `/etc/my.cnf` ...

Comment: The maximum number of threads (processes in fact on linux) per user (or system wide) was reached when trying to create a new thread.

Comment: It also could be a memory issue as indicated by this bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5656

Comment: tmp_table_size                 = 1024M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 256M
query_cache_limit              = 256M
max_connections                = 502400
wait_timeout                   = 60
thread_cache_size              = 100
open_files_limit               = 1000000
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 900000

Answer (score 3):

Add a line like this to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
mysql  soft  nproc  4096
```

Then restart mysql

Comment: Can You please let me know what it did?

Comment: https://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit
Raises the upper bound on the number of files that can opened by the mysql process.

Answer (score 2):

It seem that your system reach to the maximum number of thread per process, please verify status of your system about threads:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

$ echo 'SHOW STATUS;' | mysql | grep -i threads
```

You should also review your current settings about thread_cache_size, This link may help: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/408845/what-value-of-thread-cache-size-should-i-use

PS: This topics should be posted in serverfault.com